# django easy-Thumbnails does not work

Tags: python, django

In my django project I am using Easy Thumbnails.

Locally every thing is working properly while on the production server I am facing a little strange situation

On the production, the library is successfully installed and I have followed the same steps in the readme file on github

In my settings I have put the following lines

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
'': {
    'small': {'size': (75, 75), 'crop': True},
    'regular': {'crop': "scale" , 'size': (500, 0) },
    'galleryThum': {'crop': True , 'size': (120, 120) },
},
```

}

I have a model class called Photo which contains an imageField called image

In the template I am doing the following

1- `{% load thumbnail %}`

2- `<img src="{{photo.image|thumbnail_url:'galleryThum'}}"/>`

Locally every thing is working fine while on the production server the images does not appear. When I replace the line `<img src="{{photo.image|thumbnail_url:'galleryThum'}}"/>` with this line `<img src="{{photo.image.url}}"/>` the image appears normally

Where would be the problem ?

Comment: What is the error message you get? Can you provide error messages from apache or so? I have had problems with permissions in your media folder. Make sure easy_thumbnails is allowed to create the thumbnails in the folder where your photos are stored.

Comment: Anas , i'm also in your situation , it works on production but did you get it to work on development?

Comment: Iirc, PIL might needs libjpeg and similar to work. I know I always install JPEG- and PNG-related libraries as one of the first steps, so I'm not sure if PIL really needs them or not, but it does work.

Comment: I have jpeg/png support and it's still not working for me. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033962/django-easy-thumbnails-invalidimageformaterror

Answer (score 1):

for debian/ubuntu,

yum install freetype freetype-devel libjpeg libjpeg-devel

should be:

sudo apt-get install libwebp4 libwebp4-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev liblcms1 liblcms1-dev libwebp4 libwebp4-dev

Comment: I have jpeg/png support and it's still not working for me. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033962/django-easy-thumbnails-invalidimageformaterror

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your server setup is, but `pip install pil` on CentOS 6.3 didn't install any dependencies for me. Here was my fix:

Uninstall `PIL` if it's installed: `pip uninstall pil`, then:

```
yum install freetype freetype-devel libjpeg libjpeg-devel
pip install pillow
```

(Or `apt-get install` instead of `yum install` if on Linux.)

After installing `pillow`, you should see some output similar to this at the end:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SETUP SUMMARY (Pillow 2.0.0 fork, originally based on PIL 1.1.7)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      2.0.0 (Pillow)
platform     linux2 2.7.3 (default, Apr 30 2013, 20:15:01)
             [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support not available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have jpeg/png support and it's still not working for me. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033962/django-easy-thumbnails-invalidimageformaterror